# Java: How to write a program to recognize only uppercase letters using boolean and string

Tags: java

I am new to programming and Java. I am having a problem which is to make my program recognize Uppercase letters only and display error message if the user input is non-alphabetic character. I am instructed to use boolean and strings for this problem. 
Thanks!

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a single letter, and I will tell you what the corresponding digit is on the telephone:");
String letter = in.nextLine();
String upperCase = letter.toUpperCase();
boolean letter = letter.hasUpperCase();


if (letter.equals("A") || letter.equals("B") || letter.equals("C")){
 System.out.println("The digit 2 corresponds to the letter " + letter + " on the telephone.");
}
else if{
  System.out.println("Please enter a letter.")
}
```

Comment: `boolean letter = letter.hasUpperCase();` reassigns letter as a `boolean` rather than a `String`. You should get compiler errors in your if-statement. Correct them.

Comment: When you say you are having a problem, could you tell me what problem you're having? I think this looks like a good start (I see minor issues, but let's talk about your problem first!)

Comment: You need to verify that user entered exactly one character (`letter.length() == 1`), then extract that character (`letter.charAt(0)`), and verify it is an uppercase letter (between `'A'` and `'Z'` inclusive).

Comment: i do not know how to write a code that tells the program to recognize uppercase letters only

Comment: There actually is no `hasUpperCase()` method in `String` class as far as I can remember. Also when saying "use boolean and strings", does that mean "ONLY" or can you use other stuff as well? This problem is solvable with a little addition which `String` itself doesn't have, but its part does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for only uppercase letters then one approach would be to check each character's ASCII value to see if it falls in the range between 65 and 90. If all characters in the string meet this criterion then you have a string containing only A-Z. If not, you can then show an error message as appropriate. See the example below based on your code.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Your message here");
    String userInput = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    // Here you don't know what they entered
    // but looking at your code, you want 
    // only ONE uppercase character

    // validate the input
    boolean validInput = false;

    if (userInput.length() == 1) {
        char letter = userInput.charAt(0);
        if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 90) {
            validInput = true;
        }
    }

    // handle accordingly
    if (validInput) {
        // your logic here
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your error message");
    }
```

EDIT -- what to do to check if the character is a number or a symbol

...

```
    // Here you don't know what they entered

    // the validation / execution changes based on your needs
    // suggestion: define other methods

    if (userInput.length() == 1) {
        char c = userInput.charAt(0);

        // what kind of character is it?
        if (isUppercaseLetter(c)) {
            // do something with the uppercase letter
        } else if (isDigit(c)) {
            // do something with the digit
        } else if (isSymbol(c)) {
            // do something with the symbol
        } else {
            // whatever else it might be, this could be an error message
        }
    }
```

...

```
// methods here
private boolean isUppercaseLetter(char c) {
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'); // ascii codes 65 to 90
}

private boolean isDigit(char c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9'); // ascii codes 30 to 39
}

private boolean isSymbol(char c) {
    return (c >= '!' && c <= '/'); // 21 to 47, modify based on acceptable symbols
}
```

Comment: Just to improve the legibility 65 can be changed by 'A' and 90 by 'Z'

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. If it solves your problem, consider accepting the answer. If not, provide more detail and I'll try to help. As Marcos noted, you can swap the ascii values for their character equivalents; see the "Printable Characters" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for more information.

Comment: Because of your help my codes work fine. Can you please show how to do the same thing for non-alphabetic characters. In the situation when the user inputs numbers or symbols.

Comment: You need to take a look at the `if (letter >= 65 && letter <= 90) {` part of the code and modify it according to the ascii characters you can accept.

Comment: if (letters >= 00 && letters <= 64){
        isNotLetter = true;
      }
    }
    if (isNotLetter == false){
     System.out.println("Invalid characters"); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you ask. But I modify your code, so it can run based on my way of looking at it.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a single letter, and I will tell you what the corresponding digit is on the telephone:");
    String letter = in.nextLine();
    boolean hasUpper = false;


    if (letter.equals("A") || letter.equals("B") || letter.equals("C")){
        hasUpper = true;
        System.out.println("The digit 2 corresponds to the letter " + letter + " on the telephone.");
    }
    else if(letter.equals("a") || letter.equals("b") || letter.equals("c")){
        System.out.println("Error! The letter has to be uppercase.");
    }
    else{
         System.out.println("Please enter a letter.");
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion. My code is not completed yet. If the user input is a lowercase "a", the output should be "Error! The letter has to be uppercase."  and by using boolean.